# Authentication before opening a Websocket

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

What is the State-of-the-art way to secure a websocket with authentication?

The problem is, that everybody can download the js file and see the host and port to which websocket the page connects.
The only way which comes to my mind is: open a wss(secure websocket) and send for example credentials and close the connection on the server-side if the credentials are wrong?

Comment: Yes the problem is. Some libs, for example https://github.com/theturtle32/WebSocket-Node suggest to use server-side cross origin protection. wss is just encrypt your traffic.

Comment: ok, basically the client has to provide some information(e.g username+password) and the server desides if he accepts the connection or not?

Comment: Usually authentication produces throw http, client gets some secret token (session), which saves in cookies. The token can be the key while opening socket connection (ws://localhost:8000?token=1234)

Comment: Thank you! and how can I verify if the token is a valid one in node.js?

Comment: The same as work server-side session mechanics. You should store somewhere list of opened tokens and check coming one among them. Good decision is to use Redis sets with expire option for store sessions.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, a WebSocket request has an `Origin` HTTP header that indicates the domain where the client is running. So if your site is www.whatever.com, and you get a WebSocket request with a www.smartass.com as origin, you can reject it. That will prevent other from letting users connect to your service inadvertently. That said, it is still possible to access your service from everywhere by faking that header, but must be done on purpose.

WebSockets uses HTTP negotiation, so they can carry cookies during negotiation. If your WebSocket service is in the same domain or subdomain that the rest of your site you can share cookies. So for example, when your user logins successfully, a cookie will be returned that he will use to authenticate himself in each HTTP interaction with the server, including the WebSocket service. Just reject any request without valid cookies and you are done.

If they are in different domains, you can do what you said, use a loginRequest/loginResponse messages to authenticate the connection.

Comment: Can I do the authentication other than ordinary HTTP-Authentication via .htaccess files? I'm thinking if I wanna use a yubikey or something else to have a 2-way authentication...is that possible via HTTP?

Comment: Websocket negotiations play along with http, so it may be possible, but I don't know for sure.